# Javascript Array of Functions with if condition

Tags: javascript

I want it to work only with one function, the problem is with different variations all functions are calling.
I want to loop all function of object, and on event click one of this functions to work

```
var array_of_functions = [
    function() { first_function('a string') },
    function() { second_function('a string') },
    function() { third_function('a string') },
    function() { fourth_function('a string') }
]

for (i = 0; i < array_of_functions.length; i++) {
 if(array_of_functions[i] == someRanFunc ) {
    array_of_functions[i]();
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible to see what are you asking. This should be edited with a clear problem statement, or should be closed as offtopic or unclear what you asking.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. What do you want this for? What does not work? What is `someRanFunc`?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. `someRanFunc()` would be the equivalent code to what you've written.

Comment: I think you are trying to test if i-th function is equal to someRanFunc. Remember functions are nothing but objects and objects are equal only by reference.

Comment: try this one `array_of_functions[array_of_functions.join(',').split(',').indexOf(someRanFunc.toString())]()`

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the function by doing toString()

For example

```
var someRanFunc = function() { first_function('a string') }
var array_of_functions = [
    function() { first_function('a string') },
    function() { second_function('a string') },
    function() { third_function('a string') },
    function() { fourth_function('a string') }
]

for (i = 0; i < array_of_functions.length; i++) {
 if(array_of_functions[i].toString() == someRanFunc.toString() ) {
    array_of_functions[i]();
 }
}
```

or by comparing the name of the function

```
var someRanFunc = function a() { first_function('a string') }
var array_of_functions = [
    function a() { first_function('a string') },
    function b() { second_function('a string') },
    function c() { third_function('a string') },
    function d() { fourth_function('a string') }
]

for (i = 0; i < array_of_functions.length; i++) {
 if(array_of_functions[i].name == someRanFunc.name ) {
    array_of_functions[i]();
 }
}
```

Comment: @VladyslavNaidonov can you share a fiddle to show what you have tried?